# ServiceNow attachments in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, servicenow

How to download or upload attachments to **servicenow** from camel connector. The project is setup with camel-servicenow (v2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1) in maven. Creating, retrieve and updating of tickets is working fine, however, not able to download any attachments using Attachment resource.

Comment: can you enrich your question with an example ?

Comment: I am using servicenow connector of jboss, need to upload and download attachments

Comment: Maybe this test https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-servicenow/camel-servicenow-component/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/servicenow/ServiceNowAttachmentTest.java helps but it would ne nice to have an example of what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download :

```
url = "https4://" 
        +  instance
        + ".service-now.com/api/now/v1/attachment?sysparm_query="
        + "table_name=" 
        + table 
        + "%5Etable_sys_id=" 
        + sysId
        + "&authenticationPreemptive=true&authUsername=" 
        + username 
        + "&authPassword="
        + password
        + "&authMethod=Basic";
```

In route definition :

```
from("direct:servicenowAttachmentDownload").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET")).recipientList().simple("${header.url}")
```

Upload :

```
url = "https4://"
        + instance
        + ".service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name="
        + table
        + "&table_sys_id="
        + sysId
        + "&file_name="
        + attachmentName
        + "&authenticationPreemptive=true&authUsername="
        + username
        + "&authPassword="
        + password
        + "&authMethod=Basic";
```

In route definition :

```
from("direct:servicenowAttachmentUpload").process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntityBuilder.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            String filename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME);

            String filePath = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("filePath");
            String attachmentName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("attachmentName");

            File file = new File(filePath);
            multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("upload",
                    new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, attachmentName));
            exchange.getIn().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
        }
    }).removeHeaders("CamelHttp*").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")).recipientList()
            .simple("${header.url}")
```